# why doesnt print property file.lastModifiedDate of file?

Tags: javascript, angular, file-upload, angular2-forms, last-modified

```
<tr *ngFor="let file of filesList; let i=index">
      <td><input class="form-control input-sm" value="{{ file.url }}"/></td>
      <td>{{ file.size/1024 | round }} Kb</td>
      <td>{{ file.lastModifiedDate }} </td>
</tr>
```

I see file has this property in console log, how can I print it? [image]

Answer (score 1):

[Date Pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe) will help you, please see below:

```
<td>{{file.lastModifiedDate | date}}</td>
```

This will format your date, see my link above for different formats

Comment: can I ask you, is it a bad practice to use many pipe directives? e.g. I used  round pipe before

Comment: No, it's not - Pipes are there to be used :)

Comment: and, sorry, can I need to create  a new "date.pipe.ts"  and there  import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from "@angular/core"; again? like it was in my round.pipe.ts and then again it include in AppModule?

Comment: it is not help. if I set '<td>{{file.lastModifiedDate | date }}</td> ' - its nothing print still. I also include 'import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';' in app.module and when set in NgModule - CommonModule have error - "Cannot find name 'CommonModule'."

Comment: I tried - nothing. were my actions be correct to include pipe?

Answer (score 1):

I found:

> Though present in early draft of the File API spec, this property has been removed from it and is now non-standard. Use File.lastModified instead.

and 
`<td>{{ file.modified * 1000 | date:'MM-dd-yyyy' }} </td>`
it helped me